# How to interpret the plots of smooths from a GAM object

Tags: r, regression, data-visualization, generalized-additive-model, splines

I am reading a text which is trying to demonstrate that enabling the `select = TRUE` option in the GAM function doesn't get rid of all the non-significant variables in the GAMs.

The text uses the following function to generate a GAM object in R:

```
(GAMFit <- gam(y ~ s(x1) + s(x2) + s(x3) + s(x4) + s(x5) + s(x6) + s(x7) + s(x8) + s(x9) + s(x10), select = TRUE))
```

Here the $x_i$ are generated such that we know a priori that only $x_1$ and $x_2$ are significant predictors of $y$. All the $x_i$ are randomly generated and:

```
y <- 3 + 2 * x1 + sin(x2) + rnorm(N, 0, 3)
```

The text then generates plots of all the predictors and the smooths using the following:

```
plot(GAMfit)
```

The resultant plots are then supposed to prove that the smooths of $x_3, ..., x_{10}$ are insignificant predictors. What is the best way of reading the resultant plots? I'm not sure how the plots show what the text is trying to prove.

Some sample plots: [image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Would you mind sharing a link to the text? Success here might depend on whether the basis dimension for $f(x_2)$ is sufficiently large to model the sin function, so it would be nice to explore that with an actual working example rather than having to simulate the data myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Answer

I'm not sure which text you are referring to, but I think the answer is fairly straightforward.

Our $x_1$ here clearly has a consistent positive linear effect on $y$ and has a very narrow credible interval band around the regression line, so it's not surprising that this is a statistically significant effect. We can't say that about the other two. For $x_3$, the effect is nearly nonexistent, as it only influences $y$ at $x_3$'s minimum and maximum values. For $x_4$, the line is literally flat, and that should pretty clearly indicate that it doesn't have any influence on $y$.

Usually if a GAM smooth has a statistically significant effect on the outcome, the spline fit will either be linear and strong enough in magnitude to become statistically significant, or it will be so curvilinear that it becomes pretty clear that the predictors have some influence on $y$, just not in as straightforward a sense as linear fits.

**Edit**: Below are some reading materials which may be useful to you per the comments.

##### Reading Material

- Pedersen, E. J., Miller, D. L., Simpson, G. L., & Ross, N. (2019). Hierarchical generalized additive models in ecology: An introduction with mgcv. PeerJ, 7, e6876. https://doi.org/10.7717/peerj.6876
- Simpson, G. L. (2018). Modelling palaeoecological time series using generalised additive models. Frontiers in Ecology and Evolution, 6(149), 1–21. https://doi.org/10.3389/fevo.2018.00149
- Wood, S. N. (2017). Generalized additive models: An introduction with R (2nd ed.). CRC Press, Taylor and Francis Group.

Comment: Thanks for your response. If you don't mind explaining further, what are the two dotted lines in the graphs supposed to represent? I understand that the solid line in the middle is the regression line. Also, does the shading at the bottom of the graph mean anything?

Comment: The dotted lines (I assume you mean the one around the regression) is the credible interval I mentioned, which estimates the certainty/uncertainty in the regression line. I note that this is not a *confidence interval* like typical regressions because the splines are usually estimated with a Bayesian exponential prior. The shading at the bottom of the plot is the "rug", which shows where each data point is in the distribution of the predictor. If we use $x_4$ as an example, there are only about three data points that approach $-4$, while several are shown between $-2$ and $2$.

Comment: One can't really know *exactly* when splines will become statistically significant, one can only make assumptions based off what they see, where here it seems pretty clear. Without seeing the data points in their raw form, I can only assume that the curved tails at the ends are because of the splines interpolating somewhat poorly at the ends of the distribution, but that isn't clear from just these plots alone (normal scatterplots will give you more of a clue). Exposure to regression theory and many GAM fits will improve your inference about the data generating process (DGP) belying the model.

Comment: I've included some reading materials that may be more useful. I particularly like Gavin Simpson's articles on this topic. Simon Wood's book is the most modern canonical text on the subject, but some parts can be pretty difficult for those who aren't as math inclined (though one can navigate around a good amount of that by simply running the codes and building inference based off what he says).